# How to run MirrorMaker 2.0 in production?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-mirrormaker

From the documentation, I see MirrorMaker 2.0 like this on the command line -

`./bin/connect-mirror-maker.sh mm2.properties`

In my case I can go to an EC2 instance and enter this command.

But what is the correct practice if this needs to run for many days. It is possible that EC2 instance can get terminated etc.

Therefore, I am trying to find out what are best practices if you need to run MirrorMaker 2.0 for a long period and want to make sure that it is able to stay up and running without any manual intervention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have many options, these include:

- Add it as a service to systemd. Then you can specify that it [should be started automatically and restarted on failure](https://www.2daygeek.com/linux-systemd-auto-restart-services-when-down/). systemd is very common now, but if you're not running systemd, there are many other process managers. https://superuser.com/a/687188/80826.
- Running in a Docker container, where you can specify a [restart policy](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/start-containers-automatically/#use-a-restart-policy).